# Metabox types list

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, metabox, customization

For example, in below code snippet, there are some types for custom metabox input fields such as text and textarea.So, I want to learn other types.I searched it on google also w.se.com but I couldnt.For example, I want to learn e-mail type.

```
array(
    'name' => 'Instagram',
    'desc' => 'You should write Instagram link here',
    'id' => $prefix . 'text-instagram',
    'type' => 'text',
    'std' => 'https://www.instagram.com/britneyspears/?hl=tr'
),
array(
    'name' => 'Additional Post Description while hover thumbnail',
    'desc' => 'The text will shown on post thumbnail via our elementor post widget',
    'id' => $prefix . 'textarea',
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'std' => 'Its amazing story so I dont know where must I start to tell...'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you specify if you are using a plugin to develop these metaboxes, to narrow down the answer.

If you're working with CMB2, you're looking for text_url field ty (see the [full list](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types) in CMB2 GitHub page.).

If you're working with MetaBox, then text would be the one as url fields are implicit within it. See the [full list of field types here](https://docs.metabox.io/field-settings/#field-types).

Same goes for ACF (text field) or page_link. Check the full list of available field types in their [official docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#field-types/).

But then there's the option to create your own field types.

Hope this helps.